# PowerShell + Excel.Application add sheets problem

Tags: excel, powershell

I am trying to implement a script to update some Excel sheets/cells.

For this I am using Windows PowerShell ISE with the following code:

```
# open application
$document = New-Object -ComObject excel.application 
$document.Application.Visible = $true
$document.DisplayAlerts = $false
# Create workbook
$workbook = $document.Workbooks.Add()
```

After this, I can use the following command to see which sheets I have:

```
$workbook.Sheets | Select-Object -Property Name
```

And it works perfectly. The problem is when I add a new sheet with the following:

```
$workbook = $document.Sheets.Add()
```

It creates the new sheet, but… when I use the command to see the sheet names, it does not show anything, looks like the `Sheets.Add()` crashes something…

Can someone help me with this topic? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Perhaps, you need `$workbook.sheets.add()`?

Comment: Damn, you are my savior! Yes, it was the problem, the wrong indication.